# How to generate a mesh-based lightning effect?

Tags: modeling

How can I generate a mesh-based branching lightning effect (to eventually be 3D printed) similar to the one on [this miniature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpC5l.jpg)? I'm looking for something I can anchor to one or more points on the model, and optionally have it go off in the air.

I found a guide for manually creating the kind of mesh I'm looking for, but it requires manually remaking it any time the pose for the model changes, which I'd like to avoid.

[image]

Comment: I think there are a number of ways to achieve this effect. Of the several I've tried, my preferred one is the Shrinkwrap-based method described in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaiVc51WKcc